# Get every element after the third on smarty

Tags: smarty, prestashop

hello I want to apply an specific class to every 3rd element and the next one getting the third element was easy I used

```
{if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 3}omega{else}
```

but getting the next one its being tricky, i tried with

```
{if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 3+1}omega{else}
```

but doesnt work, do you know whats the correct way of writing?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try it right now, but it should be

{if ($smarty.foreach.products.index-1) % 3 == 0}omega{else}

you should get omega when index = 4, 7, 10....

Answer (score 0):

use iteration and index:

```
{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration is div by 3 or  $smarty.foreach.products.index is div by 3}omega{/if}
```

iteration starts counting at 1 (1,2,3,...), so the third element will get the class and as index starts counting at 0 (0,1,2,3,...), the 4th element will also get the class

read more about foreach in smarty at http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Use .iteration

> iteration contains the current loop iteration and always starts at
>   one, unlike index. It is incremented by one on each iteration.

Smarty 3

```
{foreach $myArray as $foo}
  {if $foo@iteration % 3 == 0}
```

Smarty 2

```
{foreach from=$myArray item=i name=foo}
  {if $smarty.foreach.foo.iteration % 3 == 0}
```